# Русские реалии в английском

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Сегодня читал статью "Русские заимствования в английском". В списке заимствований была и "шуба". Задумался. Разве можно считать "шубу" русской реалией?
А что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Не кажется ли вам, что сейчас уже шуба не воспринимается как русская реалия? Шуба уже давно стала обыденным делом. Согласен, тогда, может быть, шубы не было в Европе. И европейцы позаимствовали шубу. Просто сейчас, на мой взгляд, вряд ли у кого шуба ассоциируется с русской культурой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Англичане "открыли" Россию в XVI веке, и с тех пор вели с нами торговлю. К тому времени пушного зверя в Западной Европе почти не осталась, даже самые богатые люди могли себе позволить если только меховой воротник. То, что у нас в этом ходила вся знать, не могло не производить впечатление. Так что ничего удивительного в том, что для полностью меховой одежды стали использовать русское слово, нет. Меха были одним из основных продуктов экспорта России ещё долгое время.